# How can a low-rep user remove an accidental downvote?

Tags: support, down-votes

During a workout my phone interpreted the motions of my body as prompts and I ended up downvoting an answer to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125023/orange-on-turquoise#125026). The time limit had passed for me to undo the downvote. On other sites I make a trivial edit, then remove the downvote, then undo the edit; but here that will not work because my editing would have to pass review. **When I attempted such an edit, it was rejected.** Apart from begging for soneone with editing priveleges to bail me out, what can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Make a useful edit**. You're correct that a no-op edit whose sole purpose is to unlock your vote is not accepted. Edits are supposed to be improvements, *especially suggested edits*, which other people have to review. I see you have since [suggested a useful edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/56798) which identified and fixed typos. This will likely be approved and then you'll be set.

As a side note, try to make useful edits even when you have full edit rights.

Comment: Good advice generally. Coincidence that I got that edit approved at about the sane time, maybe?

Comment: If you look at the edit review task (click the link in my answer) you'll see that I reviewed the edit right before posting this answer.